# How do I make 1920x1080 screen resolution permanent? Lubuntu 20.04 Virtualbox Windows host

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, display-resolution

I found this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080
xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080
```

Gets me the resolution I want until I start Linux back up and it returns to 600x800.

How do I make Lubuntu keep these settings after restarting?

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the manual

https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.10/monitor_settings.html?highlight=resolution

You'll note resolution settings can be changed at Preferences -> LXQt.settings -> Monitor.Settings[image]

Clicking APPLY will cause the settings to be saved only for the current session, but they won't be saved for subsequent sessions (logins).

If you click SAVE as well; the changes will take place on subsequent sessions as well.

Note:  This is a LXQt setting; so it does **not** impact your machine until after you've started and logged into a LXQt session; ie. Lubuntu uses `sddm` as the greeter, which is not part of LXQt thus has it's own settings.

Comment: This was *tested* on a QA-test install of a 20.04.3 system, plus *live* system (same 20.04.3 media *as it's our next release so it's what I've got ready at hand*) and works perfectly. In both cases I changed the display resolution from 1920x1080 to 1280x1024 (which I knew my display could handle), saved, logged and and back in. The install system was rebooted and it still worked (*live* system of course wasn't).

Comment: *I came across a few Qt5 issues in the play that can get in the way depending on how you setup your displays, they are known issues are only resolved in later (non-LTS) releases of Qt5, but these can be worked around; but for someone not aware of them; it could look like it failed to work if you come across one of the Qt5 LTS bugs. These issues don't occur in later releases*

Comment: Apply and Save does not keep the resolution desired and returns to 800x600. Anything else you have describe I don't understand. Here are the following terms I don't know: LXQt, LXQt session, sddm, sddm greeter, QA-test install, live system, Qt5.

Comment: It was tested and works perfectly on hardware.  The box I used to test that on was `hp dc7700 (c2d-e6320, 5gb, nvidia quadro nvs 290)` but I have a list of 24 other boxes where it's also worked. Because you're talking about a VM, the settings on your HOST OS can limit what the guest OS actually sees (of hardware) and thus the settings may not work; but that will be a config issue on the host that is incorrect and/or changed each time.  I'm also assuming it's an actual install (not live/persistent; though it works with `mkusb` created persistent images if used on the same hardware each time)

Comment: The *live* may have been tested on `hp 8200 elite sff (i5-2400, 8gb, nvidia quadro 600)`; i can't check as the daily was ~two days old so wasn't recorded as a QA-test.  Today's *focal* daily shows no changes for the packages I watch out for so I won't likely update that ISO & today either; but it was tested & worked as expected (ie. your VM works; your issue maybe your HOST OS & config setup)

Comment: @EricHuelin neither of Guiver's comments have been 'rude', 'unfriendly', or 'unkind'.  Save your rude/unfriendly/unkind flags for posts and comments that *actually are rude*, please.

Comment: And calling people names is equally rude ("fanboys" in the context you're using them, Eric, is name calling and rude).  Comments are now disabled on this answer due to offtopic comments that won't help anything.